# Place border around page even if <body> does not fill screen

Tags: html, css

I apologize if this is a stupid question, I am quite new to web dev. I am trying to border an entire page.

I currently have `body{border: 20px black ridge}`. This borders the entire body element which works. However, if the body is not as big as the view port, the border just wraps around the content but not the edge of the page. I have also tried `height:100%` on the body element, but that doesn't seem to fill the page.

I could just add a certain amount of `<br/>` depending on view port size with JS, but this seems like a clunky solution.

**EXAMPLE**

CSS:

```
body{border: 20px black ridge}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Try `min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);` on `body`

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `{ box-sizing: border-box; min-height: 100vh; }` to the `body`.
In this case, `body` height always will be equal or more than a browser window height. And `box-sizing: border-box` will allow a browser to include border heights to a 100vh height value, not calculate it as `100vh + 20px + 20px`

Answer (score -2):

Well actually what most people dont know is you can grab the `html`, `head` and even `title` tags and style them.

What will work most of the time is add a border on the `html` tag to see if it fills the screen.

However, i am not sure if it will scale with respect to the body or if it is going to be at least 100% of the height at all times.

Comment: It did not scale to the size of the page, thank you for the response though.

Comment: @exciteabletom Well to me that seems like no matter what, the html and body will only scale to the height amount of the combined content. So if the content of the page (tags nested in the body) has a height of 500, the html and body will have the height of 500 unless you have elements outside of the body.

Comment: I would try and do body { height: 100vh; } The vh unit meaning viewport hight is a unit that has a fixed size of 0 to 100. 1vh is 1% of the current viewport, and 100vh meaning 100% of the current viewport. However vh is not the same as %. If the element scales outside of the current viewport then its 1% is more then 1vh.